# Using google maps api, how to find all ZIP codes within a radius?

Tags: location, maps, zipcode, radius

I need to find all zipcodes within a given radius. I've googled a page that does exactly that: https://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm but its author doesnt respond. Any ideas how he did that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a product ZipCodeAPI that does that.
Use this API to find all US zip codes within a given radius of a zip code. Send a GET request to https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/<api_key>/radius./<zip_code>//.

There is a free subscription and a paid subscription available.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).